# Prefetch/Superfetch slows the system down. What can be the reason?

Tags: windows-7, performance, superfetch, prefetch

I have a Windows 7 x64 home premium (I do know about end of life)

Multiple disks and HDD as a system disk, non system SSD disk.

I disabled superfetch/prefetch during memory usage troubleshooting and now have significantly better responsivity, which should not be the thing. Also, looks like the reason of increased memory usage was one of them.

What can cause performance degradation of this kind on Windows 7?

**edit:** Issues I'm investigated was a "disappeared" ram: I got an message about system running out of memory with only browser started, and sum of listed processes ~4gb (I have 16gb ram and 32gb cache)

Performance issues I had before looks like a delay between input and GUI reaction, like program is being polled from hdd cache. Most noticeable it was for Vivaldi browser tabs (can take multiple seconds if there was many enough tabs. None of that I'm observing with now.

Comment: For a period after startup Superfetch will be fetching in data as it does its job. Your system should be "normal" after it has finished, which could be up to 10 minutes or so. Mechanical HDDs, especially laptop ones, can be incredibly slow with poor latency. If you have an SSD then it should be your boot drive.

Comment: No, it is a long term effect. Usually I have ~1 week system uptime. Issues I'm investigated was a "disappeared" ram: I got an message about system running out of memory with only browser started, and sum of listed processes ~4gb (I have 16gb ram and 32gb cache)

Comment: The actual effects and problems it is causing you would be a good thing to [edit] into your question.

Comment: Another weird behavior was ProcMon active logging (SysinternalsSuite suite) making total used ram value to rise *fast* (1gb over minute) while process used only  20mb of ram. Cleaning procmon's log returns total used ram value to initial one.

With Prefetch/Superfetch disabled this behavior is not observed

Comment: > a good thing to edit into your question. 
I will do